# database file set to a collation not built into sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, sqlite3-python

How do I read a database file set to a collation not built into sqlite?

```
select * from {tablename}
```

When I enter the query, I get the error

> no such collation sequence: UNICODE_en-US_LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE.